# Xcode Dont understand these constraints and its not working the way I want it

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints, frame

So I can seem to get these `constraints` to work properly. I did something on one of my `ViewControllers` and it works perfect. I just don't remember how I did it.

So when I update `constraints` on the new `ViewController`, then I get warnings stating Frame for "object" will be different at run time. Then yellow dashed outlines of the selected object appear lower in the ViewController. Then if I `click Editor -> Update Frames`, it shifts everything down to where the yellow dashed boxes are. I don't wan't this to happen. I want my objects in the `ViewController` to go where I place them.

Why does it place the yellow dashed box lower than where I actually have it placed?

This is with one item selected. See how the yellow dashed box is lower than I want it. Now when I was setting this up I have the `UIScrollView` to fit the whole canvas. That is how the other `ViewController` is set up.

[image]

Comment: Use Update Constraints instead of Update Frames

Comment: I tried that and it seems to have no effect.

Comment: can you show screenshot of your Storyboard?

Comment: It has been updated. I hope this is helpful.

Comment: delete the Top and Bottom constraints and set them again

Comment: Select your `UIViewController` that has the `UIScrollView`. Now go to your *attributes inspector* and where you set the `UIViewController` title, below it, there ought to be an option, *adjust scroll view insets* ensure it is unchecked. If that doesn't fix it, ensure you are adding, top and bottom spacing to the correct elements.

Comment: Rikh - that worked but I had to go back and update all the `@IBOutlets`

Comment: So, why did the bluish tint disappear on other `ViewControllers` and why did it change some of the constraints? Do I need to have all `ViewControllers` like this? Why did the other `ViewController` allow me up to update how I wanted them?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so update. I got to playing around and I found that the navigation bar had a lot to do with that. I deleted the `segue` that lead into the `ViewController` and set on the constraints where I wanted everything. Then I re-added the `segue` and everything was where I wanted it. I don't know if this is the correct way or the best way to achieve this.

Also I got to playing around more and found that I didn't have to delete the `segue` I could just put everything behind the navigation bar, add constraints then update the frame. Again I am not sure if this the proper way to do it but it did work the way I needed it to work.